# Taylor Expansion of $ \frac{1}{x} $ about x = 0

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I'm confused with the following problem:

The expression $ \frac{1}{x} $ is clearly not defined at x = 0. However, I read that it could be expressed as a series using the idea $ \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L $ where $ L $ is the "independent term".

More specifically, I am trying to evaluate $ f(z) $ about $ z=0 $ where $ z=\displaystyle\frac{1}{x} $

I've no idea how to start. Could someone please guide me?

Comment: who told you that $\frac{1}{x}$ can be expanded about x=0? however $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$ is certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor expansion around 0 of $f(x)$ is:
$$
f(x) = f(0) + f'(0) x + \frac{f''(0)}{2!} x^2 + \cdots
$$
For this to make sense, all the derivatives at $x = 0$ have to be finite; in particular, $f(0)$ must exist. In your case it doesn't (it and all derivatives are infinite), so there is no Taylor expansion.